# Set KeyValuePair in KafkaAppender

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, log4j2

Here i want to set key value pair. all other features are working.

i want to use log4j2.properties file.

```
appender.kafka=org.apache.kafka
appender.kafka.type= kafka
appender.kafka.name= kafkaAppender
appender.kafka.topic= NewTopic
appender.kafka.property.type=Property
appender.kafka.property.name=bootstrap.servers
appender.kafka.property.value=host:ip
appender.kafka.property2.type=Property
appender.kafka.property2.name=group.id
appender.kafka.property2.value=new_group_id
appender.kafka.layout.type = JSONLayout
appender.kafka.property3.type=KeyValuePair  <--- not work
appender.kafka.property3.name=originalGuid  <--- not work
appender.kafka.property3.value= value       <--- not work
```

it works when i try it this way. but i dont want to use log4j2.xml file.

```
       <Kafka name="kafkaLogAppender" topic="${kafka.topic.logs}">
            <JsonLayout>
                <KeyValuePair key="guid" value="$${ctx:guid:-}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="originalGuid" value="$${ctx:originalGuid:-}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="gateGroupCode" value="$${ctx:gateGroupCode:-}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="037Message" value="$${ctx:037Message:-}"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="titleMessage" value="$${ctx:titleMessage:-}"/>
            </JsonLayout>
            <Property name="bootstrap.servers">${bootstrap.servers}</Property>
            <Property name="group.id">${group.id}</Property>
            <MarkerFilter marker="${audit.logmarker}" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </Kafka>
```

but when I tried in properties file, I couldn't set the keyvaluepair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `KeyValuePair` is a subcomponent of `JsonLayout`, its prefix needs to start with `appender.kafka.layout`, e.g.:

```
appender.kafka.layout.k1.type=KeyValuePair
appender.kafka.layout.k1.name=originalGuid
appender.kafka.layout.k1.value=value
```

Comment: thank you so much. it works for me.

appender.kafka.layout.k1.type=KeyValuePair
appender.kafka.layout.k1.key=originalGuid
appender.kafka.layout.k1.value= $${ctx:originalGuid:-}